# Writing in a file without erase with f.write()

Tags: python

I need to write a python script to iterate calculations on several instances, unfortunately the last test overwrites all those before.

Do you know a way to avoid this?
Here is my code, thank you!

```
import subprocess
import os
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
import sys


files = [f for f in listdir("data/dataAlea2_50") if isfile(join("data/dataAlea2_50", f))]
K = [2,5]

commande = "g++ -std=c++11 *.cpp -o main -Wall"


subprocess.getoutput(commande)

for file in files:
    for k in K:


        tmp = subprocess.getoutput("./main" +" " + str(k) + " data/dataAlea2_50/"+ file)
        f = open("resulat.txt","w+")
        f.write("Voici les resultats pour k = " + str(k) + " et pour les données :" + file )
        f.write(tmp)


f.close()
```

Comment: have you tried to append?

Comment: Use `f = open("resulat.txt","a+")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to append instead of write. For example:

```
import subprocess
import os
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
import sys


files = [f for f in listdir("data/dataAlea2_50") if isfile(join("data/dataAlea2_50", f))]
K = [2,5]

commande = "g++ -std=c++11 *.cpp -o main -Wall"


subprocess.getoutput(commande)

for file in files:
    for k in K:


        tmp = subprocess.getoutput("./main" +" " + str(k) + " data/dataAlea2_50/"+ file)
        with open("resulat.txt", "a") as f:
            f.write("Voici les resultats pour k = " + str(k) + " et pour les données :" + file )
            f.write(tmp)
```

where the important piece is using the `"a"` option instead of `"w+"` for the `open` function. You can find the full list of options [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open)

Comment: A much better solution is to open the file for writing once, before the main loop.

Answer (score 2):

Use [open mode `a`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open):

```
f = open("resulat.txt", "a")
```

Unless you’re also *reading* from `f`, there is no need to specify `+` in the open mode.

Better yet, [use a `with` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#with) to open the file.